# Stack Overflow account reset/duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-accounts, deleted-users

I usually use my Google account to log in to Stack Overflow, however when I logged in yesterday it said I had only 101 points (because I'm a member of multiple Stack Exchange sites), had no questions asked or answered.

I looked up some previous questions I answered and found my answers listed under `user785347`. Here are three answers that are listed like that:

[Html <div> element background image not displaying and nothing inside of the div also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655942/html-div-element-background-image-not-displaying-and-nothing-inside-of-the-div/29814023#29814023)

[How do I open my own inventory via a Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811161/how-do-i-open-my-own-inventory-via-a-event/29813705#29813705)

[Which is the best method to save data in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340213/which-is-the-best-method-to-save-data-in-delphi/6247718#6247718)

I can't click `user785347`'s name because it's not linked and the profile page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/785347/) doesn't show anything.

What I want to know is what happened and is their any way to revert this?

EDIT: I suppose what I'm more interested in knowing is how my SO account could have been removed.

Comment: As far as I know, this grey image on profile shown when profile is deleted.

Comment: The odd thing is I can't see a single account with 200+ rep on your network profile, yet you received the association bonus on this account. I assume that, originally, your SO account had more than 200 rep, which is how your other accounts got the bonus. If this is the case, I have to wonder if your network account is still registering that you should get the bonus, even though your original SO account has, apparently, been removed.

Comment: @Kendra maybe hidden communities?

Comment: @ryanyuyu They're only hidden on your local profile. You can't hide them on your network profile, which is what I checked. (You can test this by looking at mine, for instance- I show only 3 communities in my SO profile, but there are more on my network profile.)

Comment: @Kendra that actually explains a lot now.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @pnuts: Please have a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373201/how-should-we-handle-the-ongoing-mass-editing-on-meta) discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your account was deleted by a Stack Exchange employee. The reasons behind that were explained to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4779472/rohit-gupta), and that person can probably relay on what they were told.

For more detail, and to request these posts be re-associated with your new account, I recommend [contacting Stack Exchange directly](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) about this.

Comment: I thought the suspension comment read "...for reasons of moderation." Have these comments changed across the board or is it just for voting issues?

Comment: @apaul34208 - I think the three categories are "for rule violations", "to cool down", or "for voting irregularities". The specific suspension type determines what you see, so it won't always be the same. Been like that for years, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Oh yeah, seems like I remember seeing the "to cool down" before... I guess I assumed that they were all left deliberately vague.